# how to escape " in cmd.exe /c parameters?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I'm trying to run a command from Perl, using Windows 7's CMD /C.
The command, when run from the prompt, works fine, but needs quoting for its parameter:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\uninstgs.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.63\uninstal.txt"
```

Without the quotes, it does not work.

If I try to run this via CMD /C, I found no way to coerce CMD.EXE to pass a quoted string as parameter to the exe file. These do not work:

```
C:\>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\uninstgs.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.63\uninstal.txt"
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\uninstgs.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.63\uninstal.txt"
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\uninstgs.exe" \"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.63\uninstal.txt\"
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\uninstgs.exe" "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.63\uninstal.txt\""
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\uninstgs.exe" ""C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.63\uninstal.txt""
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\uninstgs.exe" """C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.63\uninstal.txt"""
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\uninstgs.exe" ^"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.63\uninstal.txt^"
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\uninstgs.exe" "^"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.63\uninstal.txt^""
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What syntax should I use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Funny that cmd.exe actually contains the answer.

Here's a snipped from cmd /?

```
If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
used to process quote (") characters:

1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
    on the command line are preserved:

    - no /S switch
    - exactly two quote characters
    - no special characters between the two quote characters,
      where special is one of: &<>()@^|
    - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
      two quote characters
    - the string between the two quote characters is the name
      of an executable file.

2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
    a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
    remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
    any text after the last quote character.
```

So in your case it would be:

```
C:\>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\uninstgs.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs8.63\uninstal.txt""
```

That said, it would also be possible to use the 8.3 short names and thus truncate Program Files to Progra~1 or Progra~2. Even more, you could use relative paths and first navigate to c:\Program Files(x86) before executing your command. Your command would then become:

```
C:\>cd /d "c:\Program Files (x86)" && C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C ".\gs\uninstgs.exe .\gs\gs8.63\uninstal.txt"
```

Comment: It seems to me that /S enforces the old behavior, which means a consistent use of cmd.exe to execute an arbitrary command line is cmd.exe /S /C "something that doesn't need to be "escaped" at all". I tested and used it in my project.

Comment: You can also set a % variable and use it in the command to get around this issue.